# Как убрать перенос текста под иконку?

Tags: html, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Как сделать позиционирование текста относительно первой буквы в абзаце ? ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно, чтобы текст во второй и тд строках начинался под 1 буквой 1 слова

вот мой код

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a4f6ecb8ad.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Стили</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style type="text/css">
   .lol { 
    display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr  ;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr  ;
width: 100%; 

   }
   .fa-check-circle
   {
   color: green;
   }
   i.fas 
   {
   padding-bottom:10px;
   font-size: 35px;
   margin-right: 15px;
   }

  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
   <div class ="lol"> 
   IT-инфраструктуры на предмет
готовности к переходу на отечественный софт,
разработка рекомендаций и подготовка плана
перехода
   </p>
  
   <p>
   <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
   Помощь в исполнении нормативных
документов по переходу на отечественное ПО
   </p>
   
   <p>
   <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
   Бесплатная консультация и дорожная карта
по исполнению 188- ФЗ. Проект ТЗ конкурсной
процедуры по импортозамещению ПО
   </p>
 
  
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Для начала, приведите код в порядок, устраните опечатки.

Answer (score 0):

```
i.fas, p > span{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

где `p > span` - это контейнер для твоего текста "Помощь в исполнении нормативных
документов по переходу на отечественное ПО" и "Бесплатная консультация и дорожная карта
по исполнению 188- ФЗ. Проект ТЗ конкурсной
процедуры по импортозамещению ПО"

Comment: К сожалению, такой метод поднимает иконку над текстом